# Как сделать чтение текста на сайте

Tags: php

Появилась необходимость сделать на сайте чтение текста, как например google переводчик.
Загружается текст, а потом по нажатии на кнопку начинает читаться текст голосом
Какие нибудь есть библиотеки или сторонние сервисы как то использовать?
Сайт на php

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы здесь есть информация по технологиям синтезатора речи https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API.
Также есть у Yandex https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/, но он платный (60 коп. в минуту).